# In flutter how to get a value from function?

Tags: flutter

I am newbie in flutter i need to know one thing I am calculating some value in my function need to show this in text widget how is it possible?

This is my functions

```
  final List _questions = [
    {'would': 'Coffe1', 'rather': 'Tea', 'wouldclick': '1', 'ratherclick':'2'},
    {'would': 'Blue', 'rather': 'Red', 'wouldclick': '2', 'ratherclick':'2'},
    {'would': 'Green', 'rather': 'Yellow', 'wouldclick': '3', 'ratherclick':'2'},
  ];

  int index = 0;
  void percentage1Calculate(){
     final percentage1 = _questions[index]['wouldclick'] / _questions[index]['wouldclick'] + _questions[index]['ratherclick'] * 100;
  }
  void percentage2Calculate(){
     final percentage2 = _questions[index]['ratherclick'] / _questions[index]['wouldclick'] + _questions[index]['ratherclick'] * 100;
  }
```

And need show in a column

```
Column(
     children: <Widget>[
       Text(percentage1),
       Text(percentage2),
    ]
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your numbers look like they are actually `String` types, try converting them first before the math happens:

```
double percentage1Calculate(){
     int wouldClick = int.parse(_questions[index]['wouldclick']);
     int ratherClick = int.parse(_questions[index]['ratherclick']);
     double percentage1 = wouldClick / wouldClick + ratherClick * 100;
     return percentage1;
}
```

Then you should be able to set a variable like so:

```
Text('${percentage1Calculate()}');
```

If you make it a `get` method, you could use it like so:

```
double get percentage1Calculate {
     int wouldClick = int.parse(_questions[index]['wouldclick']);
     int ratherClick = int.parse(_questions[index]['ratherclick']);
     double percentage1 = wouldClick / wouldClick + ratherClick * 100;
     return percentage1;
}
```

```
Text('$percentage1Calculate');
```

Comment: Try 1st method its showing Invalid argument(s): The source must not be null

Comment: I made some edits just now, did you try the revised copy?

Comment: Showing in whole widget. I think problem is json format maybe

Comment: Yep, referenced invalid keys for the Map, check the edits above. I can verify this is working on my own machine.

Answer (score 0):

You can return value calculated in the function and pass it inside widget as a value.

Let's say your function returns int,

```
int percentage1Calculate(){
  final percentage1 = _questions[index]['wouldclick'] / _questions[index] ['wouldclick'] + _questions[index]['ratherclick'] * 100;
  return percentage1;
}
```

call the above function and save it in a variable,

```
int store = percentage1Calculate();
```

use it in widget like following,

```
Text(data: $store);
```

Comment: is it possible to direct call funtion in text widget ?

Comment: Try with this but its showing error Class 'String' has no instance method '/'. when i print store value

Comment: it's a totally different error search on web, This problem have been solved.

Comment: Text(percentage1Calculate().toString())